Factorization and irreducibilty for $x^n-2x^m+1$ trinomials.
I have encountered a weird phenomenon while trying to solve a problem on Reddit. Here is the phenomenon.
Let $a>b \in \mathbb{N}$ and $p_{(a,b)} = x^a - 2x^b + 1$
It seems that if $gcd(a,b,c,d) = 1, (a,b) \neq (c,d)$ and $p_{(a,b)}(x) = p_{(c,d)}(x) = 0$, where $x \in \mathbb{C}$, then it should be true that $x = 1$
I cannot prove this fact. I was hoping that the reader would be able to

"It seems that" - what exactly makes you believe this is true?

@JianingSong I should have added the caveat that $$(a,b) \neq (c,d)$$. Thanks

@lisyarus Numerical experiments with SymPy

It doesn't seem weird, if true. Polynomials usually have different roots, unless there is a reason to have a common root (or a continuous parameter which can be used for fitting, which is not the case). There is a reason to have $x=1$ as a root but apparently no reasons to have other common roots (unless $a,b,c,d$ are all even, which is ruled out by the gcd condition).

At least there is no solution with $\gcd(a,b,c,d)\le 100$. I couldn't go any further because a PARI program verifying this has already taken me $68$ minutes.

@JianingSong Maybe you meant $\max(a,b,c,d)\le 100$? $\gcd(a,b,c,d)$ is given to be $1$.

@Sil Yes, I was too sleepy at $1$ am at that time...

Is $x$ a complex number ? Or must it be real ?

@Peter Thanks for the clarification. $x$ is complex

There are many results on irreducibility and factorization of such trinomials, e.g. Schinzel's Theorem, excerpted from this 2020 survey by Koley & Reddy. $\ \ $

Beware typo in Schinzel's Theorem: first displayed equation middle factor should be  $,x^{3k}+x^{2k}\color{#c00}{-1}.\ \ $

@BillDubuque Thank you for the answer to the question. How did you find it in the literature? Would you mind posting it as an answer, so that this question may be useful for future reference?

@Vatsa I knew of such research so I found it by searching on "trinomial Schinzel". But you could also have found it by replacing "Schinzel" by "irreducible" in that search.

This is a consequence of known results on irreducibility and factorization of trinomials, e.g. see Schinzel's theorem below, excerpted from this 2020 survey by  Koley and Reddy. Beware there is typo in the Theorem: the first displayed equation middle factor should be  $\,x^{3k}+x^{2k}\color{#c00}{-1}.\ \ $


I am not a math, but If I know the answer to this kind of problem. Is it interesting in math?

@KZNobrega Answers are already know in many cases - see the linked survey
